# Как задать класс (html атрибут) тегам option в админке джанго c фильтром

Tags: python, django-admin, many-to-many

У меня есть следующий код в джанго:

```py
class CharacteristicValue(models.Model):
    characteristic = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Название характеристики:")
    value = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Значение характеристики:")
    is_general = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Является ли характеристика общей:")


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name="Название продукта:")
    characteristic = models.ManyToManyField(CharacteristicValue, verbose_name="Характеристики продукта:", blank=True)
```

у модели `CharacteristicValue` есть поле `is_general`, которое отвечает за то, что будет ли объект созданный этой модели общим. Мне нужно в админке,когда добавляешь характеристики в `MultipleSelect`, добавить класс тем тегам `option`, у кого `is_general = False`. Это нужно для того,чтобы те объекты,которые не общие, не появлялись для выбора. Я хочу задать им через JS `display: none;` Я пробывал с помощью функции `formfield_for_manytomany` и она работает. НО мне нужно, чтобы когда я добавлял характеристики с помощью плюсика справа от `MultipleSelect` они добавлялись и сохранялись. Функция `formfield_for_manytomany` не дает их сохранить, поэтому я выбрал классы.